# How to print something from a server with PHP?

Tags: php, printing

I need to make my PHP application printing something using a printer connected to the server.

In PHP 4.0, `php_printer.dll` existed, but it was discontinued.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion on how this could be done with PHP 5?

Comment: Print on the server, right?

Comment: By "print" do you mean like on paper, using a printer?  If so, you *cannot* make a user's printer start printing stuff without their consent.  Can you imagine if you could?!

Comment: More or less yes, the printer is connected to the "server" via usb, it does not have ethernet

Comment: Interesting question. You are trying to print directly with a php script to a printer connected to the computer/server running php?

Comment: If you want to print on the server, then what do you mean by "browser's print manager"?

Comment: Yes, i do. But, there is no cheat?

Comment: When you ask pro browser print something it opens a window with printing options. I want him to do it directly without going through this window

Comment: What operating system does the server run?

Comment: Does this help: http://likepie.net/2012/php_printer-dll-and-php-5-3-9/

Comment: You may try to create some temporary file like PostScript and for example run some *.bat file that will send this file to the printer.

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, its dll is to OS windows 2000 or under.

Comment: exactly how could a server-side dll in PHP possibly affect anything in a client's browser?

Comment: @Voitcus I did not your suggestion

Comment: As you refer to a DLL file I assume you are using Windows server, so _somehow_ (I don't know how) you may create a PostScript file for example in `C:/TEMP` and after you're done make PHP call external file that is old [BAT file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) that will take as argument your new filename and _somehow_ make it print (there is a [print command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_%28command%29) in MS Windows).

Comment: Side note: i think PHP isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: some other programming language can this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the output to a file and then use `exec` to print the file with the correct command (depending on the operating system).

Examples:

```
exec('lpr /some/path/to/the/file', $output);    // linux
exec('print C:\again\a\path', $output);         // windows
```

You would probably have to check if the php user has printing rights.

Comment: i trying but, DOS not use usb